# Venn Diagram of $A$ and $B$, When $A \cap B =\varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are two sets which $A \cap B =\varnothing$, can we draw their Venn diagram as follows:

[image]

Or it **MUST** be this way?

[image]

Comment: @Behzad When someone asks for explanations to a question that, yes, needs some, the OP can choose to provide these explanations instead of fixating themselves on the details of the formulation of the request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* draw it either way: any region in a Venn diagram may in principle be empty. However, if you know for a fact that $A\cap B=\varnothing$, it’s pointlessly misleading to draw it the first way: one of the main reasons for using Venn diagrams in the first place is to aid your intuition, so you should draw it in the way that best does so. In this case that’s your second picture, with disjoint regions.

Comment: On the one hand such a diagram is misleading. But on the other hand, it makes it easier to prove identities for sets. Suppose that we want to prove an identity for three sets. It's far easier to prove it for the _general_ Venn diagram, without considering emptiness or non-emptiness of any of 15 different regions in that diagram.

Comment: @Behzad: If you’re proving an identity for sets $A,B$, and $C$ that has as a hypothesis that $A\cap B=\varnothing$, you’re better off with a Venn diagram that show this hypothesis. If you don’t have such a hypothesis, then you don’t know that $A\cap B=\varnothing$, and none of this discussion is even relevant.

Comment: There will be two approaches: a) Draw multiple diagrams to cover all possible cases for three sets and prove the identity in each of them. b) Accept that _general_ Venn diagram as basis of the proof, noting that area does not necessarily show existence of element(s). The second approach is easier, isn't it?

Comment: @Behzad: We’re not even talking about the same thing. I’m talking only about the situation that you appeared to be describing in your question, in which it is **given** that $A\cap B=\varnothing$. In that situation there are no other cases to draw. If you meant to ask whether there’s any good reason to draw different Venn diagrams for different cases in proving a *general* result, then I’d say that in general the answer is *no*, but that’s not the question that you actually asked.

Answer (score 2):

It must be the second way. The first picture you drew clearly has elements (interpreted as area) in both sets, or the intersection.

Comment: Do you know any textbook explicitly stating existence of area means existence of elements?

Comment: This is not strictly speaking correct: any region in a Venn diagram may in principle be empty.

Comment: @Behzad I do not but that is the only way i have seen these diagrams used

Comment: @BrianM.Scott maybe, but then I am not sure what would be the point of drawing the second one. A and B are just both the empty set?

Comment: @qbert: There is no *maybe* here. The general Venn diagram simply displays all of the *possible* subsets generated by the sets pictured; it does not imply that all are non-empty. I don’t understand what your last question has to do with anything, but the answer to it is: *No, in the second diagram they can be any two disjoint sets; this includes the possibility that one or both are empty.*

Comment: I interpreted you as meaning that points would have to be drawn to indicate elements of the set. And what I meant by *maybe* is that *may in principle be true*, but as you say, venn diagrams are meant to aid in intuition and are usually drawn in a way not to obfuscate the meaning. Therefore, if OP wants to be well understood by other human beings, he or she is better off drawing the second one imo.